# Execute JavaScript code once a browser window/tab is opened for the first time

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Is there a way to execute JavaScript code only once when a window or a tab in a browser is opened and then never again for the whole life-cycle of this window/tab (even when navigated away)?

Comment: you mean : even if you navigate in differents pages in the same window/tab ?

Comment: @jeremycastelli Yes

Comment: You could use cookies to record that you have run the script and then only run it if the cookie isn't set. The user can, of course, remove the cookie - but most of the time they won't do that.

Comment: @LeoFarmer But when the user opens a new tab I want the code to run again. Only once per tab.

Comment: Like @LeoFarmer said, use cookies

Comment: cookies won't do the job, since they are persistent across all tabs. SessionStorage is the way to go, as posted by @naveen

Comment: @burnedikt you right, sessionstorage is the way to go

Comment: How about using window.history.length and only run your javascript if it equals 1?

Answer (score 5):

One way to use `window.sessionStorage` like this.

```
if (!window.sessionStorage.getItem("isExecuted")) {
    //execute code
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("isExecuted", true);
}
```

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

> The sessionStorage property allows you to access a session Storage
>   object. sessionStorage is similar to Window.localStorage, the only
>   difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set,
>   data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends.
>   A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives
>   over page reloads and restores. **Opening a page in a new tab or window
>   will cause a new session to be initiated**, which differs from how
>   session cookies work.

Comment: I tried this but the problem is that when you "open in new tab" for example, the sessionStorage from the tab you navigate from is copied to the new tab.

Comment: it doesnt appear in firefox. will check when back to work

Comment: It occurred with IE11

Comment: I just found following known issue (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2980020). But it does not seem to be resolved. It still occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution based on checking the window.history.length is 1 (i.e. the first time they've been to this window/tab). It also does a check that they've not simply refreshed the page.

```
if(window.history.length === 1 && performance.navigation.type  !== 1){
     alert("show me once per tab");
}
```

If you put the script you want to run once where I have my alert, it should work for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **localStorage**.

> Local storage is per origin (per domain and protocol). All pages, from one origin, can store and access the same data.
>
> The localStorage object stores the data with no expiration date. The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year.

```
localStorage.getItem('key');
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

Doc: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: But this will persist even after they close the browser.

Comment: "The localStorage object stores the data with no expiration date. The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year."

Comment: That's exactly what I said and exactly the problem. They need it to be cleared if the tab closes.

Comment: Oh true.. Sorry, I did the opposite.