# Executing JS code only when tab is open

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script which called a JS function every 2.5 seconds. This is the code that I use,

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    getMsgs();
    setInterval(function() {
      getMsgs();
    }, 2500);
</script>
```

This code keeps on executing even if I am on an other tab on the browser. How can I make this only execute when the tab with that specific page is open?

Comment: look into http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/detect-browser-window-focus

Comment: Duplicate, look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957980/javascript-should-run-only-if-tab-browser-window-is-focused and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389328/detect-if-browser-tab-has-focus

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361392/execute-javascript-code-once-a-browser-window-tab-is-opened-for-the-first-time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect If Browser Tab Has Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389328/detect-if-browser-tab-has-focus)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389328/detect-if-browser-tab-has-focus), you could use

```
window.onfocus and window.onblur
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach would be to check whether `document.hidden` is false

```
   setInterval(function() {
         if(document.hidden === false) {
             getMsgs();
         }
    }, 2500);
```